# Capturar o id de um botão gerado dinamicamente com JS puro

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Olá!

No html tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="likes-btn-1" type="button"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="likes-btn-2" type="button"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
  </button>
  <button id="likes-btn-3" type="button"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
  </button>    
</div>
```

Tenho a instrução em jQuery que captura o clique em qualquer um dos botões e me retorna apenas o numero final do id referente ao botão clicado:

```js
$(document).on("click", "button[id*='likes-btn-']", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[2];
  alert(id);
})
```

Porém, tem um detalhe. Possuo uma operação que vai gerar dinamicamente outros botões depois da página ser completamente carregada. Com o jQuery eu consigo obter o clique no botão gerado dinamicamente por ter usado a instrução `on('click')`. Mas como faria isso usando JS Nativo/Puro?

Alguém tem algum exemplo para me passar? Eu tentei dessa forma:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const likesBtns = document.querySelectorAll('button[id*="likes-btn-"]');
  for (const btn of likesBtns) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const id = btn.id.split('-')[2];
        alert(id);
    });
  }
});
```

Entretanto, depois que os botões são gerados dinamicamente na página não funciona mais.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que estás fazendo errado. Use *dataset* para armazenar o `id` do botão e use uma `class` para atribuir eventos à um grupo de elementos, por exemplo:

```
<button type="button" data-id="1"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary likes-btn">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" data-id="2"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary likes-btn">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
</button>
```

A class `likes-btn` será usada paga atribuir o evento click, que poderá ser capturada com:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(e.target.classList.contains('likes-btn')){
            console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Teste:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(e.target.classList.contains('likes-btn')){
            console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" data-id="1"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary likes-btn">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    1
</button>
<button type="button" data-id="2"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary likes-btn">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    2
</button>
```

Comment:  Fechou, muito obrigado por essa dica.